# OSX - Uninstall older version of an existing application

Tags: macos, installation, inno-setup, node-webkit, dmg

I have created an application with node webkit. I packaged and distributed the first mac version of it. I am about to distribute the next version of the same. I want an installer or something similar to [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) for windows which would help me uninstall the previous version of my application and install the newer version.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have packed your app in a DMG to release the first version. If you need to do a cleanup on the existing installation, you can use a PKG-DMG combination. PKG allows you to have pre-install/post install scripts. You can do your uninstallation/cleanup via these scripts.

[Packages](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/34613/packages) is a tool that can help you create a PKG file. If you want to automate this, you can use command line [pkgutil](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html). You can add the PKG directly to DMG instead of app.